# Errors in using Matrxmodels package in R: CHOLMOD factorization was unsuccessful

Tags: r, linear-regression, sparse-matrix

I am trying to estimate a linear model using sparse matrices. The code I used is:

```
MatrixModels:::lm.fit.sparse( Dc, y, w = NULL, offset = NULL,
                                          method = c("cholesky"),
                                          tol = 1e-7, singular.ok = TRUE, order = NULL,
                                          transpose = FALSE);
```

The error message is:

```
Error in .solve.dgC.chol(as(if (transpose) tx else t(x), "CsparseMatrix"),  : 
  CHOLMOD factorization was unsuccessful
In addition: Warning message:
In .solve.dgC.chol(as(if (transpose) tx else t(x), "CsparseMatrix"),  :
  Cholmod warning 'matrix not positive definite' at file ../Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c, line 729
```

Dc is a sparse matrix with class dgCMatrix and y is a vector. Dc is the product matrix of D and W', where D is a sparse matrix with sparsity level of more than 95%. W' is a transform matrix. I have checked the columns and row of Dc and there is no all-zero column/row.

The possible reason for the error is that Dc is too dense to be used in lm.fit.sparse. However, the dimension of the matrix is too large to use `matrix` class (dimension of Dc is 1311247*8192). Could anyone please point out to me if I did anything wrong or how I could solve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! Could you please edit your question by copy/pasting the error message(s) that you see when you execute your code? Also, if feasible, it would be ideal to have some sample data that [reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @xilliam Thank you for responding! I just found out that the error message changes if the sample size change. However, it would easy to regenerate Dc, it is a sparse matrix with only two non-zero elements in each row. W is a transform matrix generates by `GenW` in package `wavethresh`, with n=8192. Hope to hear more from you!

Comment: Alas, I am not familiar with the analysis your are attempting, but it would make it easier for others in the community to help, if you added some code that would allow them to generate the Dc object.  Also, not knowing much about this package, have you looked to see what is on line 729 of at file "../Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c"? The error seems to suggest a problem arises there.Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for helping me rephrase my question!